# "See your responses" link broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, responses

I just logged into Super User and received the **"You have 1 new answer. See your responses."** banner.

However, clicking on the given responses link https://superuser.com/users/recent/472/2011-03-23/2011-03-29?tab=responses directs to "Page Not Found".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old messages in the system generated before our recent change (that properly links to your profile) were not cleaned up correctly.  This has now been done; no more users logging in will get a link pointing to a page that no longer exists.

New links point to the appropriate responses or favorite tabs on your profile...and existing links were updated to point to the new corresponding location as well.

Answer (score 2):

The `/users/recent/*` page, which was previously linked to by the little envelope (by your username, where there is a downward triangle now) before it was removed. That page was replaced by the new tabs in your profile page. It is probably just a bug that the banner still links there. The proper link for you should be https://superuser.com/users/472/alex-angas?tab=responses. Up until recently, the other page still existed, but was not supposed to be linked to, but it has now been removed completely.